# Call Skype numbers from Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight application in which I display some phone numbers. I want that numbers to be displayed as links and when the user clicks on the links to be redirected to skype. (The same as on html).

This is the equivalent in html (just to understand what i need):

```
<a href="callto:+11 11 111 11 11"> +11 11 111 11 11</a>
```

In silverlight I tried with:

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding}" NavigateUri="{Binding StringFormat=callto:\{0\}}" />
```

but I get System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to navigate to callto:+11 11 111 11 11.

Does somebody knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try using Javascript to invoke that sort of anchor?  If you're able to do this via Javascript, try using the Eval function to invoke the Javascript from Silverlight:

[HtmlPage.Window.Eval();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmlwindow.eval%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late, but if you still want to keep it in Silverlight code, then this will work:

```
Public Class MyHyperLink : Inherits HyperlinkButton
Sub New(ByVal uri As String)
    MyBase.NavigateUri = New Uri(uri)
End Sub

Public Sub Execute()
    Application.Current.Host.Content.IsFullScreen = False
    MyBase.TargetName = "_blank"
    MyBase.OnClick()
End Sub
```

End Class

And to call, add the following code::

```
Dim nav As New MyHyperLink(URL)
nav.Execute()
```